# package access class |(different between public and protected)

Tags: java

if i have a pacakage access class somthing like this:

```
package AA;

class A {    
  // ...    
}
```

which is only accessed by classes on package `AA`. What is the difference between declaring on this class a  methods as a `protected` or `public`?
Isn't it is the same because the  class only accessed from its pacakge ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package AA might have a public class B that extends A.

In that case, a class C from a different package may create an instance of B and call any public methods of A for that instance.

If, however, you define methods of A as protected, C would have to be a sub-class of B in order to call those methods.

```
package AA;
class A 
{
    public void foo() {}
    protected void bar() {}
}

package AA;
public class B extends A 
{

}

package BB;
public class C extends B
{
    public void func ()
    {
        super.bar (); // OK, since bar is protected and C extends B
                      // which extends A
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.foo(); // OK, since foo is public
        b.bar(); // doesn't compile, since bar is protected
    }
}
```

Comment: The different package restriction for `C` is important, from the same package, `C` could access the `protected` fields/methods too without extending either `A` or `B`. (`protected` includes package private access.)

Comment: @GáborBakos Yes, that's why C is in a different package in my example.

Answer (score 0):

It makes difference when using reflection, like Class.getMethods()